# Calculate mean of serial pairs of values by group

Tags: r, grouping

**Objective**: calculate the mean of each pair of values by group in a dataframe

**Example data:**

```
mtcars[1:10, 1:2] %>%
   arrange(cyl)

 mpg cyl
22.8   4
24.4   4
22.8   4
21.0   6
21.0   6
21.4   6
18.1   6
19.2   6
18.7   8
14.3   8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
mpg   cyl   avg
22.8   4     -
24.4   4     23.6
22.8   4     23.6
21.0   6     -
21.0   6     21.0
21.4   6     21.2
18.1   6     19.75
19.2   6     18.65
18.7   8     -
14.3   8     16.5
```

Thought I could use `dplyr::lag` or `dplyr::slice` to do this, but haven't got it working.  Not married to dplyr, any solution would be appreciated...

**Attempt:**

```
group_by(mtcars, gear) %>%
   summarise(pairmean=mean(c(mpg, lag(mpg))))
```

Comment: I never thought of this as a moving average problem, though I do find the answers to your question useful.  Didn't find your question based on apparently lack of nomenclature similarity.  Fwiw, for my purposes the order of values is not relevant (despite my use of arrange).

Comment: @akrun It's right that OP didn't use the word moving average; but from the description one can only conclude that what OP wants is a moving average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a rolling mean (`rollmean` from `zoo`) grouped by 'cyl'

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
mtcars[1:10, 1:2] %>%
        arrange(cyl) %>% 
        group_by(cyl) %>%
        mutate(avg = rollmean(mpg, 2, na.pad = TRUE, align = "right"))
```

Comment: Marvellous as always! Thx

Comment: See also `roll_meanr()` from `RcppRoll` package. Faster than `zoo::rollmean()` for rolling mean on larger data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method with `ave`.

```
# get data
temp <- mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl), c("mpg", "cyl")]

# calculate value pairwise means
temp$avg <- ave(temp$mpg, temp$cyl, FUN=function(i) (i + c(NA, head(i, -1))) / 2)
```

Here, mpg is added to a lagged value and divided by 2. The lagged value is constructed using `head` with the final element removed (`-1`) and an NA concatenated to the initial position.

This returns

```
head(temp)
                mpg cyl   avg
Datsun 710     22.8   4    NA
Merc 240D      24.4   4 23.60
Merc 230       22.8   4 23.60
Fiat 128       32.4   4 27.60
Honda Civic    30.4   4 31.40
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 32.15
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`...

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(pairmean=(mpg+lag(mpg))/2)
```